# How do I prevent bootstrap input fields to expand in md width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know how to maintain the inline format and avoid bootstrap3 input fields to expand (block) when changing the width? Thanks!

Note:  I would also want to prevent the label to go above the field when tightening the window.

Thank you very much!

```
<!-- example -->
<div class="container">

    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="firstname">First Name</label>  
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">

                </div>
                </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YsFm5/7/

Comment: You can just overwrite the behavior if you don't like it.

Comment: I like the behaviour but not the one used in this particular form... thanks

Comment: Then change it on that particular form... it's not like bootstrap it's absolute and you have to take all the sh*t they have written for default. Add a class and style it using it, don't use only the prewritten boostrap code...

Comment: Set a `max-width` on your `.form-horizontal`. You can also add a class as @drip noted, with the `max-width` applied. **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YsFm5/8/)**

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there any way to prevent the label to go above the field when tightening the window?

Comment: Are you saying you do not want the label to wrap? And yes, use media queries for whatever breakpoint you want to target. By default, BS wraps labels on its smallest breakpoint. You'll need to check your HTML and make sure it's following the same pattern as BS docs.

Comment: You can also find the breaks in the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid